# Reverse String, Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, reverse

[C# code for reversing a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJsxM.png)

I couldn't understand this part

```cs
arr[name.Length - i] = name[i - 1];
```

Let us have a `name` of 5 characters. so the value of the `arr` will be 4, right?

Then in the loop, the looping variable is also taking the same length, so its initial value will be 4, too.

In the first iteration, the value of `arr[4 - 4]` will be `arr[0]` and `name[4 - 1]` will be `name[3]`, so the first index of `arr` is copied with the fourth index of `name`.

How is the original name stored in reversed order in `arr`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("What is your name: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var arr = new char[name.Length];

            for (var i = name.Length; i > 0; i--)
                arr[name.Length - i] = name[i - 1];

            var reversed = new string(arr);
            Console.WriteLine(reversed);
        }
```

Comment: Please include your code as text, not an image.  Have you stepped through your code in a debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: included code as text @LanceU.Matthews

Comment: This looks like an odd way to do it. Generally it's best to iterate forwards instead of backwards (unless there's a specific need). Also try to use values that are zero-based rather than 1-based as much as possible when dealing with arrays etc. I.e. You your iterator variable i should range between 0 and name.Length - 1 (rather than name.Lenght doen to 1). Doing these things will make the code simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Print character `arr[name.Length - i]` and `name[i - 1]` in each iteration of for loop, you will understand what is exactly happening while reversing the string. If this will not give you an answer then please elaborate your question

Comment: Does the code you have work? If so, have you stepped through it, line by line, char by char? If you do, your questions will be answered. If it doesn't work, I'd expect that you have one or more _Off by one_ errors; that's what happens in code like this

Comment: This code can be shortened to `var arr = name.ToCharArray(); Array.Reverse(arr); var reversed = new String(arr);` or with LINQ `var reversed = new String(name.Reverse().ToArray())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question: Strings and arrays are zero-indexed. I.e. the first element is at index 0. The last is at Length - 1.

The code in your example is not very well-written. It breaks a couple of basic coding principles.

1. Iterate forwards, unless there is a very specific need to go backwards. In this case, there is not.
2. Use zero-based variables when doing any code involving strings and arrays.

The example breaks both these, and I think that's part of what it makes it hard to read, but let's try.

Looking at the iteration, if Length is 5 as you suggested then i starts at 5 and goes down to 1. When i is 5: (name.Length - i) = 0, and i - 1 = 4, so the array index 0 (the first in the array) gets the character at position 4 (which is the 5th character).

On the next iteration, i is 4: (name.Length - i) = 1, and i - 1 = 3, so the array index 1 (the second in the array) gets the character at position 3 (which is the 4th character).

And so on.

Here's a slightly nicer version of the same algorithm. Hopefully, it is a bit easier to read.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("What is your name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    int n = name.Length;
    char[] arr = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = name[n - 1 - i];
    string reversed = new String(arr);
    Console.WriteLine(reversed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced the image of original code here.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name? ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        var arr = new char[name.Length];
        
        for (var i = name.Length; i > 0; i--){
            arr[name.Length -1] = name[i-1];
        }
        var reversed = new string(arr);
        Console.WriteLine(reversed);
        
    }
}
```

It looks like the indexing is just off a little.  You want to take the length of the name that you've entered (the end of it) and take the characters starting from the end back to the beginning of the word.  Below I've changed a few variable names to add a little more meaning to the code.

```
public static void CorrectedMain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name? ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        
        char[] reversedLetters = new char[name.Length];
        for (var i = name.Length; i > 0; i--){
            reversedLetters[i-1] = name[name.Length -i ];
        }
        var reversed = new string(reversedLetters);
        Console.WriteLine(reversed);
    }
```

If you enter Thomas in the first block you get back T, if you run the code in the second block you will get back samohT.

Here is a fiddle of it.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/txwyd1